# Readonly attrib

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a read-only attribute here. Can you help me with the code in here that if the box is checked my average row will be read-only?

```
<input type="text" name="average[]" class="average" 
id="average_<?php echo $row['student_no']; ?>" value="<?php echo
$row['average_pts']; ?>"  >
<input type="checkbox" name="disable[<?php echo $row['student_no']; ?>]" id="disable"          value="1" class="disable" <?php if ($row['disable_comp']=='1') { echo "checked=\"checked\""; } ?>>

$(".disable").change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');
      $("input").unbind('keyup', computeValues);

      var checked=$("#able").is(':checked');

   }else{
      $("input").bind('keyup', computeValues).trigger('keyup');
       $("#average").prop('readonly');
   }
});
```

Comment: Please clean this up.

Comment: Unrelated, but is there a reason that you are assigning different value's to the "checked" variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the condition is correct, you just want to use the attr function:

```
$('#able').attr('readonly', true);
```

Comment: the #able is not the row of my average so ill just replace it with average?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".disable").on('change', function() {
    if ( this.checked ) $("#able").prop('readonly', true);
});
```

Comment: can i replace the #able by average because im planning to get the average row to become read only

Answer (score 0):

$("#average").attr("readonly", true);
$("#average").prop("readonly", true);

try using both of them as attr some times will set but never works in the way of functionality 
so we need to use both of them ......(on page load to recognise we must use attr.)
plz find the [Attributes vs. Properties.](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)